# Difference among plain code, interface builder and storyboard

Tags: ios, interface-builder, storyboard

In iOS programming, using latest iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

1. Is there anything that only plain code (programmatically create all things such UI elements) can achieve, and neither of the other two (interface builder, storyboard) can't?
2. Is there anything that only interface builder can achieve, and neither of the other two can't? Such as auto layout setting.
3. Is there anything that only storyboard can achieve, and neither of the other two can't?
4. Is storyboard equivalent to putting all xib file together?
5. Is it possible to transfer project made by plain code (name it project A) to project using interface builder or storyboard (name it project B) by making some changes in the project A? Because the only method as far as I know, is to create a new project C and copy everything in project A into project C using interface builder. The need for this kind of transferring from plain code to interface builder or storyboard is partially due to questions 1, 2 and 3 above.
6. Is it possible to transfer project using interface builder or storyboard (name it project D) to project with plain code only (name it project E) by just removing .xib or .storyboard file, and remove all those IBAction or IBOutlet tags? Still, all I can do now is still create new project and do it again using different approach.

### Reference

1. [Why I Don’t Use Interface Builder](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder)

Comment: There's nothing that using only plain code can accomplish that the others can't because the others are frequently complimented with some programmatic adjustments.

Comment: @nhgrif then Is storyboard equivalent to putting all xib file together?

Comment: IB is cool because you can rapidly prototype something up but you can only do so much with it. Programmatically creating your views is more work but allows much more flexibility. I haven't used storyboards before (and never will) but it sounds like it is an attempt to reach a good balance between the two.

Comment: @nhgrif Actually there are many things that can be achieved only in code. One example: `- [UINavigationItem setRightBarButonItems:`]

Comment: @LeoNatan And using a storyboard doesn't prohibit you from doing that.

Comment: Storyboard and nib only allow for `setRightBarButonItem:`, not `setRightBarButonItems:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:

The interface builder has limited support for custom properties on custom `UIView`s, doesn't expose the full complement of properties on Apple's views and doesn't allow the use of any fonts other than those built into the OS — if you want to use your own fonts then you need to include them and then set them programmatically. One workaround I've seen is to alias OS fonts you don't use to fonts you have included and method swizzle `UIFont` to substitute the one for the other, but obviously that sort of thing starts significantly to undercut the purpose of the visual tool.

Similarly it doesn't let you do anything with `CALayer`s, although it is possible to set some properties using KVC in interface builder. Constraints are not sufficient to meet all layout possibilities — e.g. suppose you have a box at the top with a size that is dictated by its content, its content being a string returned from a server.

2.

Nothing significant that I'm aware of. In the old days it was the only way to set a custom `UINavigationBar` class for a `UINavigationController` since Apple had neglected to provide a public API for that, but that's been addressed. I guess there may be other similar examples that I'm not aware of but, if so, they'll be fringe uses resulting from an oversight.

3.

It can make your project digestible once it's 1,000 controllers big. Storyboards allow setting the big picture of how view controllers interact with each other, what data they pass, how they pass it. Storyboards also allow for specifying view controller containment.

A storyboard can also specify the contents of a table view, which a NIB can't, and which if you were doing in code would be done in a different and much messier way. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/05/07/static-table-views-with-storyboards.html). Similarly, it can create static collection views.

4.

A storyboard links various controllers, and in doing so it specifies the linking transitions. Those would need to be supplied programmatically if you were using NIBs. It also gives you an good visual idea of application flow.

5.

You can transition one view controller at a time; the process would to pick a controller to adapt, create the nib, wire things up, rip out your view creation code from the source, then probably add a custom version of `init` that calls `initWithNibName:...` on the superclass.

There are no automated tools.

6.

If you were to remove the NIB or storyboard, you'd remove all record of how the views should be laid out — and indeed that they should be created at all. You'd then need to write that all out programmatically.

Comment: 3. is incorrect. Storyboards can do static tables in a manner that is different from having to implement it in-code.

Comment: @LeoNatan you're unambiguously correct. I've made that correction and flagged this post as community wiki as it feels like other differences may be lurking beyond the limits of my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to presume that the difference between storyboards, XIB/NIBs, and programmatically created views rests solely in the functional capabilities of each. Clearly, though, the advantage of minimizing the amount of code one has to write, rests more in the speed of development, ease of maintenance, and the ability to reduce the chance of defects. The purpose of storyboards, for example, is not to be able to do things that you couldn't do in NIBs or programmatically created views, but largely to make it easier for you to develop and maintain such apps.

That notwithstanding:

1. There are plenty of things that you can do in code that you cannot accomplish with IB alone, e.g. auto layout constraints with multipliers, custom appearance stuff, custom transitions, advanced custom containers, etc. Another way of phrasing that is that some user interfaces require you to delve into code, even when designing the UI in IB.
2. There is nothing that I know of that you can do in IB that you can't also achieve in code (but often requiring more effort to achieve), e.g. cell prototypes, etc.
3. There are things that storyboards make easier to do than NIBs or programmatically generated code (e.g. cell prototypes, unwind segues, etc.), but I don't believe there is anything you can do in storyboards that you couldn't achieve in code (with more effort).
4. Storyboards are not just a visual representation between a series of NIBs (though that is an advantage in itself). Storyboards offer features that NIBs alone cannot reproduce without the use of additional code. So storyboards not only visually capture the flow of an application, but they also minimize the amount of code one has to write, and as such, storyboards are an interesting combination of design tool, development methodology and productivity tool.
5. Generally, yes, you can convert an app to one that uses storyboards, for example, but it will often require considerable refactoring of the code.
6. Yes, of course you could convert a storyboard app to a code only rendition, but you'll have to add a lot of code, generally code that is far harder to maintain than the storyboard was, but you can do it.

Comment: Constraints with multipliers will be available in Interface Builder soon. :-)

Comment: @LeoNatan Cool. That's consistent with the evolution of IB, that it helps us do more and more of our UI with each generation, but there will probably always be some (many?) features for which we'll have to resort to code.

Comment: Yes, of course! I was just having a small victory hooray wight he multipliers. :-)